# Vibrate in dynamic pattern

Tags: android

I'm coming from Actionscript 3 and new to Java. I'm trying to make a vibrate pattern half of which is fixed and half of which is dynamic. For eg:

```
long[] vibratePattern = {100,100,100,100} //fixed pattern
if(some_condition) vibratePattern.append(400);
if(some_condition) vibratePattern.append(200);
if(some_condition) vibratePattern.append(100);
```

But long[] [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144549/append-values-dynamically-into-an-long-array) have any append or add method.

I tied creating ArrayList but the method [Vibrator.vibrate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#vibrate%28long%5B%5D,%20int%29) takes long[] as parameter.

So my question is how can I make long[] array with half fixed item and half dynamic item and pass it to Vibrator.vibrate method. Can I create some other list and pass it as long[] to the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using gauva following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1698098

So I only had to `Longs.toArray(foundLongs);`

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList has a `toArray()` method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this at home and accept the answer accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately it returns object but not long[]. Any idea what I might be missing?